# cron job scheduling timing for excecuting the script

Tags: unix, cron

I need to execute a script through cron expression that is  5 days per week (Mon-Fri) between 6pm and 7am GMT.

please advise what will be the cron expression for this..

I have tried this as ...

```
0 00 23 ? * MON-FRI
```

Answer (score 2):

as the format is as follows:

```
 +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
 |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
 |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
 |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
 |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
 |  |  |  |  |
 *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
```

you may want it to be:

```
 * 6 * * 1-5 command
```

This will work every minute from 6.00 to 6.59. If you need it to execute also at 7.00:

```
 * 6 * * 1-5 command
 0 7 * * 1-5 command
```

and if you want from 6.00 to 7.59, every minute:

```
 * 6-7 * * 1-5 command
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but as  i mention .. need to execute a script through cron expression that is 5 days per week (Mon-Fri) between 6pm and 7am GMT and only once so which one i will choose

Comment: Ah, so it is only once in that period. Then, just `0 6 * * 1-5 command`. Note that it will work with your local time. Check your difference with GMT to balance it.